# jquery .live to .on in jquery upgrade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm upgrading the jQuery on my website to jQuery v1.10.1 from 1.4.2 .
I'm changing all the .live functions to .on.
Now i'm having trouble with changing one of them.

```
function tb_init(domChunk){
    $(domChunk).live('click', function(){
        var t = this.title || this.name || null;
        var c = $(this).parent().parent().find('.quotation').html();
        var a = this.href || this.alt;
        var g = this.rel || false;
        var o = $(this);
        tb_show2(t,c,a,g,o);
        this.blur();
        return false;
    });
}
```

I tried changing it to:

```
$(document).on("click", domChunk, function() {
```

and:

```
$(document).on("click", $(domChunk), function() {
```

But both don't seem to work. domChunk itself is a selector like this: `"#myid li"`
The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'blur'

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a fiddle demoing the problem? `$(document).on("click", domChunk, function() {` should work.

Comment: When/where exactly do you get that error?

Comment: `this` is a dom node, you probably meant `o.blur()` instead.

Comment: Try `console.log(this)` before the blur statement. What is it that has no `blur` method? All [HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.blur) should have one.

Comment: @KevinB Why can't they use `this.blur()`? DOM nodes have a `blur` method, don't they? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.blur

Comment: @Ian typically yes, but in this case, apparently whatever `this` is doesn't have a blur method. Wrapping it in a jQuery object will at least remove the error, though commenting it out should too.

Comment: @KevinB Oh wow, I don't know how I missed the text `The error I get is: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'blur'`...ignore everything I've said :) I'm still confused on how `this` doesn't refer to a DOM element, which *should* have a `blur` method...I mean, it's in an event handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the DOM object and not to the jQuery object.

Try this instead:

```
$(this).blur();
```

or:

```
$(this).trigger('blur');
```

---

or in your code use `o` instead of `$(this)`

Comment: @ColinDeClue that is true too.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but have you tried using $(this).blur() instead of this.blur? Since it is a jQuery function...

edit: sorry I hadn't refreshed the page before answering